# Dependency property and constructor parameters with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-container

Let's say in C# I have a class called A

```
public class A : IInterfaceA
{

 [Dependency]
 B _b;


}
```

Then in B class I have a constructor like this:

```
public class B
{

...

 public B(string someParam) { ... }

...

}
```

Now, I register class A like this:

```
_unityContainer.RegisterType<IInterfaceA, A>("RegistrationA");
```

and to resolve the interface I do:

```
_unityContainer.Resolve<IInterfaceA>("RegistrationA", new ParameterOverride("someParam", "The param."));
```

Now I want to know if it is good practice to resolve the class and pass the parameters like this or I should do it another way.
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the code you posted does not work: in fact you're overriding the parameter of class `A`, while in your code the constructor with the parameter is `B`.

Generally speaking, using parameter override is not a good practice in my opinion (unless some very specifical context like a console application or a web service using an existing container but it's avoidable in most cases) for these reason:

1. Using `Resolve` looks like a Service locator: anti-pattern nowadays. You will find a lot of discussion googling about.
2. Using ParameterOverride means that the client (the caller of Resolve) knows exactly the type mapped in the container and wants that type initialized with a specific parameter. But this is just the opposite of inversion of control.

The best way is to use an abstract factory. You can add in your code and use a more flexible and SOLID abstract factory:

```
public interface BFactory {

   B Create(string bparam);

}

public class BFactoryUnity : BFactory {
   private IUnityContainer container;

   public BFactoryUnity(IUnityContainer container) {
     this.container = container;
   }

   public B Create(String bParam) {
       var b = new B(bParam);
       container.BuildUp(b);
       return b;
   }
}
```

So you can register:

```
  _unityContainer.RegisterType<IInterfaceA, A>("RegistrationA")
           .RegisterType<BFactory, BFactoryUnity>();
```

Now the client can resolve only the factory and use it:

```
var bFactory = _container.Resolve<BFactory>();
var b = bFactory.Create();
```

Now, in a big application you will need a lot of similar factories. To avoid the boilerplate code of abstract factories and implementations you can find in the web some implementation of automatic abstract factory extensions.

Comment: Hello onof, thanks for your answer !
Can I use Unity auto-factory to achieve what you've written ?
I mean something like:

`Container.RegisterType<Func<string, B>(

new InjectionFactory(c => 
        new Func<string, B>(bParam => new B(bparam)))

);`

Then 
`class BFactory
{

private Func<string, B> factory;

public BFactory(Func<string, B> factory)
{

this.factory = factory;

}

public B Create(string bParam)
{

return factory(bParam);

}`
 
Then register the factory and inject the autofactory.
I'm not sure if it can compile because I can't test it now, but that's the idea. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Yes, that's an option.